# Twitter widget loader doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to run the following code, which is supposed to load Web Intents Javascript Events - the Twitter library.

```
TwitterWidgetLoader = function(followCallback){
    window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
    var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
    js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
        twttr.events.bind('follow', function(event) {
            alert('i got this');
            if(followCallback) followCallback(event)
        });
    });
}
```

then upon document load I do:

```
new TwitterWidgetLoader()
```

and I keep getting "twttr is undefined" error. It all goes well if I run the code outside the function "TwitterWidgetLoader" though. Any feedback is appreciated.